# how to filter and then load from json file?

Tags: jquery, json, filter, load

the question might be a bit confusing :)
i have this json:

```
[
{"media_path":"2.jpg","type":"1","complete":"1"}, 
{"media_path":"2.jpg","type":"1","complete":"2"},
{"media_path":"2.jpg","type":"1","complete":"3"}
]
```

what i want to do is to load the `"media_path"` of the `"complete":"2"`

so far i have:

```
$.getJSON('image.json', function(data) {
$('<img/>').attr("src", item.media_path);
);
```

but somehow i need to filter `"complete":"2"`

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by filter `"complete":"2"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over the returned `json` and if `item.complete === "2"` load the image.

```
$.getJSON('image.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i, item){
    if(item.complete === "2"){
      $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media_path);
    }
  });
);
```

**Simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/4zFpV/).**

Comment: Pipped at the post. Word for word the same as what I was about to submit, but with 2 spaces for indent instead of 4...   +1

Comment: You might also be able to `return false` from within the `if` of the `$.each` function. Assuming you just want to find the **first** item with complete equal to "2"? This will be quicker as it terminates the iteration as soon as the first result is found